# simple ARM asm getchar segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, arm, getchar

I am using a QEMU raspberry pi emulator and trying to set up reading from the STDIN given by the command line.
ie
"./demo3 < text.txt"

However, my code is extremely short at the moment:

```
.text
.global main

main:
    bl getchar
    bx lr
```

but this section alone gives me a segmentation fault, any ideas why?

Comment: `bl` of course destroys `lr`, so you need to save and restore it, usually on the stack.

Comment: So if I use push and pop too and from the stack the segmentation fault seems to stop, but how can I get multiple chars if everytime I use bl getchar I have to restore  from the stack?

Comment: @JamesDriver You only need to restore `lr` right before you execute `bx lr`.

Comment: @fuz if this sets r0 to the result of bl getchar, should using bl printf below the bl getchar print out the character?

Comment: @JamesDriver You probably need to load a suitable formatting string (e.g. `"%c"`) and but both a pointer to the formatting string and the result of `getchar` into the right registers. Or you could call `putchar()` instead (after putting its argument into the right register). You also need to check if `getchar` signalized an end-of-file condition.

Comment: @fuz I used a bcs under the bl getchar to check if the eof has been reached but it is saying that the file I am passing in has an eof immediately despite it containing many characters

Comment: @JamesDriver That's not the right way. `getchar` doesn't set any flags. It returns `-1` when the end of file is reached, so you need to compare `r0` with `-1` to check if this is the case.

Comment: @fuz Thank you for all the help, I am pretty much there now! just need to work out how to pass multiple args to printf(%d,%f) , thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JamesDriver Assuming ARMv7. According to Procedure Call Standard -  p 15, "The first four registers r0-r3 (a1-a4) are used to pass argument values into a subroutine and to return a result value from a function" Basically, if you place something like fmt: %d %d %d\n" in .data then your func using printf may have push {lr}, ldr r0,=fmt, bl printf, & pop {pc}. Assumes r1, r2, & r3 have existing values.